# How to calculate running total for prior years in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a set of variables  in the dataset --  I want to simply calculate the running total (and the running mean) for all these variables, based on **all** prior years.

To illustrate. This is how my data looks like, including the total run variable that I want to generate.

```
country year    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  running_total

Bahamas 1990    0   0   0   0   1   NA
Bahamas 1991    0   0   1   1   0   1
Bahamas 1992    1   1   0   0   1   3
Bahamas 1993    0   0   0   0   0   6
Bahamas 1994    1   1   0   1   1   6
Bahamas 1995    0   0   1   0   0   10
Bahamas 1996    0   1   0   1   0   11
Bahamas 1997    1   0   1   0   1   13
Bahamas 1998    0   1   0   1   0   16
Bahamas 1999    1   0   1   0   1   18
Bahamas 2000    0   1   0   1   0   21
Bahamas 2001    1   0   1   0   1   23
Bahamas 2002    0   1   0   1   0   26
Bahamas 2003    1   0   0   0   1   28
Bahamas 2004    0   0   0   1   0   30
Bahamas 2005    1   1   0   0   0   31
Bahamas 2006    0   0   1   1   1   33
Bahamas 2007    1   0   0   0   0   36
Bahamas 2008    0   0   1   1   1   37
Bahamas 2009    1   1   0   0   0   40
Bahamas 2010    0   0   1   1   1   42
Bahamas 2011    1   1   0   0   0   45
Bolivia 1990    0   0   0   0   0   NA
Bolivia 1991    0   0   1   1   0   0
Bolivia 1992    0   0   0   0   0   2
Bolivia 1993    0   0   1   0   0   2
Bolivia 1994    0   0   0   0   0   3
Bolivia 1995    0   0   0   0   0   3
Bolivia 1996    0   0   0   0   0   3
Bolivia 1997    0   0   0   0   0   3
Bolivia 1998    0   0   0   0   0   3
Bolivia 1999    0   0   0   0   0   3
Bolivia 2000    0   1   0   1   0   3
Bolivia 2001    0   0   0   0   0   5
Bolivia 2002    0   0   0   0   0   5
Bolivia 2003    0   0   0   0   0   5
Bolivia 2004    0   0   0   0   0   5
Bolivia 2005    0   0   0   0   0   5
Bolivia 2006    0   0   0   0   0   5
Bolivia 2007    0   0   0   0   0   5
Bolivia 2008    0   0   0   0   1   5
Bolivia 2009    0   0   0   0   0   6
Bolivia 2010    0   0   0   0   1   6
Bolivia 2011    0   0   0   0   0   7
```

Starting year 1990 ==NA. For example,  running total for 1991 is based on 1990. Running total for 1992 is based on 1990-1991. running total for 1993 is based on 1990-1992- running total for 1994 is based on 1990-1993. And so on...until 2011. Then it starts the same procedur for new country B.

I tried the following code below but it doesn't work the way I want. Surely, I need to specify it better, but how?

```
DF$csum <- ave(DF$X1, DF$X2,DF$X3,DF$X4,DF$X5,FUN=cumsum)
```

In addition, I would like to generate running mean based on the same logic.

Any help here would be much appreciated!

> structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L,
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 2L,
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
>   2L, 2L), .Label = c("Bahamas", "Bolivia"), class = "factor"), 
>       year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 
>       1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
>       2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
>       1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
>       2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
>       2011L), X1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 0L), X2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
>       0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X4 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X5 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), running_total = c(NA, 1L, 3L, 
>       6L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 
>       31L, 33L, 36L, 37L, 40L, 42L, 45L, NA, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
>       7L)), .Names = c("country", "year", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4",  "X5", "running_total"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   -44L))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, xt := X1+X2+X3+X4+X5]
df[, rt2 := shift(cumsum(xt)), by = country]
```

Actually it can be solved with an one-liner:

```
df[, rt3 := {xt=X1+X2+X3+X4+X5; shift(cumsum(xt))}, by = country]
# Or as Ryan points out:
df[, rt2 := shift(cumsum(Reduce(`+`, .SD))) , by = country , .SDcols = grep('^X.*', names(df), value = T)]
```

All resulting in:

```
    country year X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 running_total xt rt2
 1: Bahamas 1990  0  0  0  0  1            NA  1  NA
 2: Bahamas 1991  0  0  1  1  0             1  2   1
 3: Bahamas 1992  1  1  0  0  1             3  3   3
 4: Bahamas 1993  0  0  0  0  0             6  0   6
 5: Bahamas 1994  1  1  0  1  1             6  4   6
 6: Bahamas 1995  0  0  1  0  0            10  1  10
 7: Bahamas 1996  0  1  0  1  0            11  2  11
 8: Bahamas 1997  1  0  1  0  1            13  3  13
 9: Bahamas 1998  0  1  0  1  0            16  2  16
10: Bahamas 1999  1  0  1  0  1            18  3  18
11: Bahamas 2000  0  1  0  1  0            21  2  21
12: Bahamas 2001  1  0  1  0  1            23  3  23
13: Bahamas 2002  0  1  0  1  0            26  2  26
14: Bahamas 2003  1  0  0  0  1            28  2  28
15: Bahamas 2004  0  0  0  1  0            30  1  30
16: Bahamas 2005  1  1  0  0  0            31  2  31
17: Bahamas 2006  0  0  1  1  1            33  3  33
18: Bahamas 2007  1  0  0  0  0            36  1  36
19: Bahamas 2008  0  0  1  1  1            37  3  37
20: Bahamas 2009  1  1  0  0  0            40  2  40
21: Bahamas 2010  0  0  1  1  1            42  3  42
22: Bahamas 2011  1  1  0  0  0            45  2  45
23: Bolivia 1990  0  0  0  0  0            NA  0  NA
24: Bolivia 1991  0  0  1  1  0             0  2   0
25: Bolivia 1992  0  0  0  0  0             2  0   2
26: Bolivia 1993  0  0  1  0  0             2  1   2
27: Bolivia 1994  0  0  0  0  0             3  0   3
28: Bolivia 1995  0  0  0  0  0             3  0   3
29: Bolivia 1996  0  0  0  0  0             3  0   3
30: Bolivia 1997  0  0  0  0  0             3  0   3
31: Bolivia 1998  0  0  0  0  0             3  0   3
32: Bolivia 1999  0  0  0  0  0             3  0   3
33: Bolivia 2000  0  1  0  1  0             3  2   3
34: Bolivia 2001  0  0  0  0  0             5  0   5
35: Bolivia 2002  0  0  0  0  0             5  0   5
36: Bolivia 2003  0  0  0  0  0             5  0   5
37: Bolivia 2004  0  0  0  0  0             5  0   5
38: Bolivia 2005  0  0  0  0  0             5  0   5
39: Bolivia 2006  0  0  0  0  0             5  0   5
40: Bolivia 2007  0  0  0  0  0             5  0   5
41: Bolivia 2008  0  0  0  0  1             5  1   5
42: Bolivia 2009  0  0  0  0  0             6  0   6
43: Bolivia 2010  0  0  0  0  1             6  1   6
44: Bolivia 2011  0  0  0  0  0             7  0   7
    country year X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 running_total xt rt2
```

Comment: If you want to do it all in one step, you can do `df[, rt2 := shift(cumsum(Reduce(\`+\`, .SD)))
   , by = country
   , .SDcols = grep('^X.*', names(df), value = T)]`

Comment: Could you explain why `Reduce(`+`, .SD)` is necessary?

Comment: To add all the `X` columns without typing them all out.

Comment: I see you can't do simply `sum(.SD)`, is .SD actually a list?

Comment: `.SD` is a data.table, which is a type of list, yes. You cannot do `sum(.SD)`. Try `sum(data.table(1:2, 1:2))` to see why.

Comment: This looks great. Running on my data. Is it possible to use the same code (but modified) for generating running means?

Comment: Definitely... Would be great if you could add an example... is running means of row 3 equal to 2?

Comment: I would need to think about. Thanks for this great and elegant code. It worked as expected. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
df = structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Bahamas", "Bolivia"), class = "factor"), year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L), X1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X4 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X5 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), running_total = c(NA, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 36L, 37L, 40L, 42L, 45L, NA, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L)), .Names = c("country", "year", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "running_total"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -44L))

df <- df %>% mutate(sums = X1 + X2 + X3 +X4 + X5) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% mutate(sum_shift = shift(sums), 
                              sum_shift = ifelse(is.na(sum_shift), 0, sum_shift),
                              running_total = cumsum(sum_shift))

head(df)

country year    X1  X2 X3 X4 X5   running_total sums sum_shift
1: Bahamas 1990  0  0  0  0  1             0    1         0
2: Bahamas 1991  0  0  1  1  0             1    2         1
3: Bahamas 1992  1  1  0  0  1             3    3         2
4: Bahamas 1993  0  0  0  0  0             6    0         3
5: Bahamas 1994  1  1  0  1  1             6    4         0
6: Bahamas 1995  0  0  1  0  0            10    1         4
```

This is the dplyr solution but it is basically the same as the data table solution. We create a column where we sum across the rows. Then we group by the country and and sum across and create a cumulative sum. We have to set the nas to 0 for the cumulative sums to work.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr` and `purrr`. We can split the data frame by `country`, create the `running_total` column, and then combine the data frames. Notice that this solution does not need to specify individual column names, such as `X1` and `X2`. `dat2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  split(.$country) %>%
  map_dfr(~mutate(.x, 
                  running_total = 
                    as.integer(lag(cumsum(rowSums(select(.x, starts_with("X"))))))))
```

To calculate the running mean, we can follow the same logic by adding the command to the `mutate` function. Notice that the `cummean` function is from the `dplyr` package.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  split(.$country) %>%
  map_dfr(~mutate(.x, 
                  running_total = 
                    as.integer(lag(cumsum(rowSums(select(.x, starts_with("X")))))),
                  running_mean =
                    lag(cummean(rowSums(select(.x, starts_with("X")))))))
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Bahamas", "Bolivia"), class = "factor"), year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L), X1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X4 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X5 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), running_total = c(NA, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 36L, 37L, 40L, 42L, 45L, NA, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L)), .Names = c("country", "year", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "running_total"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -44L))

dat$running_total <- NULL
```